# Invalid Timestamps MPEG-TS - Nexio Server Errors

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to copy SAP audio from a 4ch MPEG-TS file to create an 8ch MPEG-TS file to help out a TV station partner that's struggling to do it on their own, but also running into problems.

This pass copies ch 1-4 to 5-8

> ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:a -c:a copy firstpass.ts

This pass mutes 3-6 (they wanted to "move" ch3-4 to ch7-8 and silence on 3-6):

> ffmpeg -i firstpass.ts -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -filter:a:1 "volume=0" -filter:a:2 "volume=0" -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.ts

The problem is that the Nexio is rejecting it for invalid timestamps, and copyts or flagging to genpts and gendts doesn't seem to work.

It's fine with the source if I don't re-encode audio, and it's fine if I re-encode both video and audio (which we do not want to re-encode the video at all costs).

Anyone got any ideas?

FFmpeg error:

> [mpegts @ 0x7fcadd204200] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=10714614, dts=10720620, size=3646

Nexio error:

> [12:00:13] [33352 M] [XXXXX DISCONTINUITY: currentVideoFrameInfo.start = 631109472, expectedVideoFrameStart = 624238608]
> [12:00:13] [33352 M] [XXXXX SMALL DISCONTINUITY.  NOT CORRECTING TIME BASE HERE]
> [12:00:13] [33352 M] [Error: PTL Error: discontinuous time stamp is detected. Actual lxf packet start = 630053424 (frame number = 26226). Expected lxf packet start = 623182560 (frame number = 25940)]
> [12:00:13] [33352 M] [Error: PTL Error: processing is aborted (AbortImportIfMissingPacket = 1)]

Comment: Can you share the input?

Comment: @Gyan the sources are large syndicated TV programs, but here's a clip from the head of one that has the errors - https://secure.westftp.extremereach.com/public/file/mMzu58l1a0y61ZhrX7OtJQ/sample.ts - their Nexio is able to play this back as a straight copy, or if I re-encode both video and audio, but not if I just encode the audio (which is what they need).

Comment: The sample has one stereo audio stream. Aren't you working with 4ch audio?

Comment: Of course I forgot to map audio in my sample (smh).

Comment: @Gyan - I replaced it with a proper 4ch sample (again my bad). And added my workaround. They said this works and was nice to be able to help a friend of a friend with it - but I am still curious about how I can fix timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it for them by utilizing a separate audio file with silence. That way they can just copy the streams as-is and map silence in the middle.

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -i input.ts -i 2Hr_4CH_Silence.aac -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 1:a -map 0:a:1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -shortest -y output.ts
```